# no launch activity found in an App widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am developping an widget application, My problem is that the following message appears when running the application :**No Launcher activity found!,The launch will only sync the application package on the device!**

here is the code:

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <receiver android:name=".MeteoWidget"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="TabsMeteoActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MenuMeteoActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MaVilleActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MeteoJourActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="PrevisionSemaineActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ParametresActivity"></activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Meteowidget.java

```
public class MeteoWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


     @Override
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;   
        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider      
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {      
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];         
        // Create an Intent to launch TabsMeteoActivity       
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TabsMeteoActivity.class);  
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);    
        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener       
        // to the widget     
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);   
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Layout_widget, pendingIntent);       

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget        
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);     
     }
}
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

                  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:id="@+id/Layout_widget"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/widget_layout"
         android:focusable="true" 

         >


        <TextView android:id="@+id/date_jour"
         android:text="Vendredi 5 Mai"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dip"        
         android:textColor="#ffffffff"
         android:textSize="12sp"/>




        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/Layout2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_gravity="left"

         >
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/Layout3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_gravity="left"

            >
            <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txt_ville"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
               android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
               android:textSize="16sp" 
               android:text="Tunis"
                android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


            </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/Layout4"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_gravity="left"

            >
             <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/img_meteo"
               android:layout_width="70dp"
               android:layout_height="70dp"               
               android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
               android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
               android:src="@drawable/sunny_64"

              />

            <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_temp"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                   android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
                   android:textSize="16sp" 
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="#FFD700"
                   android:text="25°"/>
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/Layout5"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_gravity="left"

            >
               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_temp_min"                
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Min:22°"/>

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_temp_max"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="Max:26°"/>

         </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

my_widget_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:minWidth="160dip"
     android:minHeight="80dip"
     android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
     android:initialLayout="@layout/main"

/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should promote one Activity to be launchable to get rid of this message.

You can do this by adding the following to one of your activities (put it inside the activity tags):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```